# Key pad behaviour with table layout

Tags: codenameone

There are textfields, pickers and textArea in the table layout. When textArea is focused, the keypad appears but as soon as other part of the layout is touched, the textarea moves down (invisible by keypad).Why doesn't the keypad disappears as soon as other parts are touched? And also see the preferred time picker, it is squeezed into smaller height. Why can't I move up the whole screen height when there's components underneath the keypad?

Have a look at the video [here](https://youtu.be/y6hxQPsMDz8).

```
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(5, 2);
Container testDriveContainer = new Container(tl);

testDriveContainer.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), nameLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), nameData)
        .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), mailLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), mailData)
        .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), mobileLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), mobileData)
        .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), addressLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), addressData)
        .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(vehicleLabel)).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), vehicleData)
        .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(interestedModelLabel)).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), interestedModelData)
        .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(preferredDateLabel)).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), preferredDateData)
        .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(preferredTimeLabel)).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), preferredTimeData)
        .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(preferredLocationLabel)).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), preferredLocationData)
        .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), commentLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), commentData);

Container mainContainer = BoxLayout.encloseY(testDriveContainer);
add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainContainer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must always have a scrollable parent for text fields. Since the border layout disabled the default scrollability of the content pane you need to do something like this:

```
mainContainer.setScrollableY(true);
```

You can manually fold the vkb either with `stopEditing()` or the user can click done.

Comment: thanks.. btw what do you mean by "You can manually fold the vkb either with stopEditing() or the user can click done."

Comment: Manually: The VKB usually has a "DONE" button on iOS to fold the keyboard. On Android the back button should do that too. `stopEditing()` is a method of `TextArea` that lets you stop the editing process programmatically.